# vba access getting exceeded system resources error

Tags: vba, ms-access

> Running the code below on access 2013 I get a system resource error. My understanding is that the program can take more time but the system resource error does not make sense. My laptop has 8gb RAM and core i3. Is there a better way to do this? Values used:

1. me.yearsback= 1
2. me.valdate = 5/31/2016
3. me.period = "monthly"
   UPDATE: Used 0.5M rows first, producing the system resource error. However, when I reduce the number of rows, it runs fine.

:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Calculate_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim Months As Integer
    Dim WPmonthly As String ' field name for monthly written premium
    Dim UPRmonthly As String ' field name for monthly unearned premium
    Dim EPmonthly As String ' field name for monthly earned premium
    Dim runningDate As Date
    Dim runningDate2 As Date
    Dim useDateLower As Date
    Dim useDateUpper As Date

    Months = Me.YearsBack * 12 + Month(Me.ValDate)

    If Me.Period = "monthly" Then
        Set db = CurrentDb
        For x = 1 To Months
            runningDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -x + 1, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
            WPmonthly = "WP M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
            EPmonthly = "EP M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
            UPRmonthly = "UPR M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
            db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & WPmonthly & "] STRING;"
            db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & EPmonthly & "] STRING;"
            db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & UPRmonthly & "] STRING;"
            If x = Months Then
                runningDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -x, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
                UPRmonthly = "UPR M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
                db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & UPRmonthly & "] STRING;"
            End If
        Next

        For y = 1 To Months
            runningDate2 = Format(DateAdd("m", -y + 1, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
            useDateLower = runningDate2
            useDateUpper = Format(DateAdd("m", -y + 2, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
            WPmonthly = "WP M" & Month(runningDate2) & " " & Year(runningDate2)
            EPmonthly = "EP M" & Month(runningDate2) & " " & Year(runningDate2)
            UPRmonthly = "UPR M" & Month(runningDate2) & " " & Year(runningDate2)
            Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEPdata", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

            Do Until rs.EOF

                'Written Premium Calculation

                If rs!issueDate < useDateUpper And rs!issueDate >= useDateLower Then
                    rs.Edit
                    rs.Fields(WPmonthly) = rs!grossPremium
                    rs.Update
                End If

                'UPR Calculation

                If rs!issueDate < Me.ValDate Then
                    If rs!expiryDate < useDateUpper Then
                        rs.Edit
                        rs.Fields(UPRmonthly) = 0
                        rs.Update
                    ElseIf rs!effectiveDate < useDateUpper Then
                        rs.Edit
                        rs.Fields(UPRmonthly) = (rs!expiryDate - useDateUpper + 1) / (rs!expiryDate - rs!effectiveDate + 1) * rs!grossPremium
                        rs.Update
                    ElseIf rs!effectiveDate >= useDateUpper Then
                        rs.Edit
                        rs.Fields(UPRmonthly) = rs!grossPremium
                        rs.Update
                    Else:
                        rs.Edit
                        rs.Fields(UPRmonthly) = rs!grossPremium
                        rs.Update
                    End If
                End If

                rs.MoveNext

            Loop
            rs.Close
        Next
    End If
    db.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: While running Ms-Access operations (VBA etc.), it create lots of intermediate tables and queries and deletes them afterwards, but if during run time, size gets exceed by 2GB, VBA code gives above error. Is this happening in your case?

Comment: yes when I check the file size it exceeds 2gb.

Comment: If such is case, then you could split data in two different tables, before running VBA code, and once VBA code gets over, from Database Tools Menu, select compact and repair database option, to resize it effectively.